# Usage of の検索結果 in a sentence that split on 2 lines

Tags: grammar, written-language

Is it OK to use the phrase, say, "Keywordの検索結果" that should be split on 2 lines like the following:

> の検索結果
> **KEYWORD**

or it should always be

> **KEYWORD** 
> の検索結果

This is for a multilingual webpage header where, in English it's used like:

> Search results for 
> **KEYWORD**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should always be "**<KEYWORD>**の検索結果". You can put a line break before の if you like.

That の is like English *of*, but the word order is different. "A of B" roughly translates to "BのA". Therefore putting の at the very beginning, like your first example, makes no sense.

**EDIT**: "検索結果: **<KEYWORD>**" is an alternative.